# SQL - datetime input doesn't take the time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, casting, format

At the moment I got theses pieces of code;

Create:

```
    CREATE TABLE Vlucht(
        Vlucht_ID       int IDENTITY(1,1),
        Lid_ID          int,
        Vliegtuig_ID    int,
        VL_Vertrektijd  datetime,
        VL_Eindtijd     datetime,
        VL_Type         char(1),
        Vl_Notitie      varchar(max),

        CONSTRAINT PK_Vlucht PRIMARY KEY (Vlucht_ID),
        CONSTRAINT FK_Vlucht_Ref_Lid FOREIGN KEY (Lid_ID) REFERENCES Lid (Lid_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT FK_Vlucht_Ref_Vliegtuig FOREIGN KEY (Vliegtuig_ID) REFERENCES Vliegtuig (Vliegtuig_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT CHK_VL_type CHECK (VL_type = 'R' OR VL_type = 'L')

    )
    go
```

Insert:

```
    INSERT INTO Vlucht
    VALUES  (4, 1, '10-04-2018 14:34', '10-04-2018 15:10', 'R', 'Vlucht van Linda'),
            (5, 1, '10-04-2018 14:34', '10-04-2018 15:10', 'R', 'Vlucht van Jaap')
```

Select:

```
    SELECT FORMAT(VL_Vertrektijd, N'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm'), +
                         FORMAT(VL_Eindtijd, N'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm'), 
                         VL_Type, Vl_Notitie, V_Naam, P_Voornaam, P_Achternaam FROM Vlucht vl 
                        INNER JOIN Vliegtuig v 
                        ON v.Vliegtuig_ID = vl.Vliegtuig_ID 
                        INNER JOIN Lid l 
                        ON l.Lid_ID = vl.Lid_ID
                        INNER JOIN Persoon p 
                        ON p.Persoon_ID = l.Lid_ID
```

Result:

```
  10-04-2018 00:00
```

So it does take the date, but it refuses to input the time given. The problem probably lies within some casting of format problems.

Comment: I think you have a '+' sign that interrupts the float of the query after the first comma.

Comment: Try using an ISO 8601 datetime literal like '10-04-2018T14:34:00'.

Comment: first of all check in the table if the date and time are saved in the table. It seems that the time is not saved

select CAST('10-04-2018 15:10' as datetime)

Comment: The T-SQL parser is a bit lax and ignores the extraneous `+` concatenation operator. The same results are returned with or without it.

Comment: It saves the date, not the time and that's the problem

Comment: Another format that will succeed is {ts '2018-10-04 14:34:00'}

Comment: I've tryied to reproduce the error but  I couldn't, see the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4b3b7/3  I removed some columns to make it work

Comment: Copied it and it worked somehow, I really don't know what's different but hey it works. Thanks a lot guys!